# Update GRUB2 from Ubuntu 20.04 installed on USB to disable creation of new entry in UEFI

Tags: grub2, uefi, 20.04, usb-installation

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a USB drive. The installation was done in UEFI mode and has an EFI partition using FAT32. The problem is that when booting on a new device every time it creates an entry to UEFI called ubuntu. It remains even after removing the USB.
Another problem is that it takes a very long time to close the system by unmounting /boot/efi
Is there any easy way to solve these problems?
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Done following instruction. Here is the link [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DgGGP3Kf4H/)

Comment: Install looks normal. UEFI boots external devices from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi and description will be your flash drive's name or label. The Ubuntu entry will work only on installed system. And often when you unplug a drive the entry is changed and does not work.  Report only shows one Ubuntu entry, line 50 in report from `sudo efibootmgr -v` if running command just to list entries from terminal.

Comment: Sorry for late reply
There is the output of the command [link](https://pastebin.com/raw/F8ak76Cs)
The thing that new entry is annoying but i can life with it.
But what to do about long shutdown time? Do you have any ideas?
Big thanks for help

Comment: Best to ask about slow shutdown on separate question. But write to flash drives is normally slow. You can check log files for what is taking a long time to time out. And post that in new question. Your efibootmgr -v is essentailly same as from Boot-Repair's report and only shows one entry. When using UEFI one time boot key, do you not get an USB flash drive boot option?

Comment: There are basically two behaviours
When you start up on a new computer:
-The Kingston entry appears... when I try to boot from it, it restarts
-The Boot Menu shows the ubuntu entry, when selected it boots normally
-Ubuntu in boot menu remains even after deleting the USB
When starting on the computer where it was previously started:
-You see a ubuntu entry that boots immediately
My goal is to get an effect like in the Live USB, where the entry in the boot menu is Kingston ... and boots right away.
Thank you for your help.